# Java Socket.io client with socket.io passport server authentication

Tags: java, socket.io, passport.js, passport.socketio

I am using the https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java library, and it works. My issue is that my server is running socket.io passport and requires authentication. Does anyone know how I can authenticate my client using the socket.io-client.java library? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution according to nkzawa

```
socket.io().on(Manager.EVENT_TRANSPORT, new Emitter.Listener() 
{
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) 
    {
        Transport transport = (Transport)args[0];
        transport.on(Transport.EVENT_REQUEST_HEADERS, new Emitter.Listener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) 
            {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Map<String, String> headers = (Map<String, String>)args[0];
                // set header
                headers.put("X-SocketIO", "hi");
            }
        }).on(Transport.EVENT_RESPONSE_HEADERS, new Emitter.Listener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) 
            {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Map<String, String> headers = (Map<String, String>)args[0];
               // get header
                String value = headers.get("X-SocketIO");
            }
        });
    }
});
```